# Zend_Form can't create element in loop

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Just like in topic I try to create a form  when the elements create in loop:

```
foreach($aQuestionList as $aQuestionValue){

        $aAnswerList = $oAnswerList->getListByQuestionId($aQuestionValue['newsletter_question_id']);

        $oNote = new SilverCms_Core_Form_Element_Note('note',array('value'=>'<p>'.$aQuestionValue['newsletter_question_name'].'</p>'));
        $this->addElement($oNote);

        foreach($aAnswerList as $aAnswerValue){
            $oCheckBox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('answer');
            $oCheckBox->setLabel($aAnswerValue['newsletter_question_answer_name']);
            $oCheckBox->isArray(true);
            $oCheckBox->setCheckedValue($aAnswerValue['newsletter_question_answer_id']);
            $this->addElement($oCheckBox);
        }
    }
```

But when I whant to display the form in view

```
<?php echo $this->filterform;?>
```

it's display only last element in the array aQuestionList and the same situation is in second loop
Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the same name ('answer') for each answer checkbox, so each will override the previous one. I think you actually want the Multicheckbox form element:

```
$answer = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('answer');
foreach($aAnswerList as $aAnswerValue){
    $answer->addMultiOption($aAnswerValue['newsletter_question_answer_id'], $aAnswerValue['newsletter_question_answer_name']);
}
$this->addElement($answer);
```

this will give you a checkbox and label for each option.

Comment: Even more if you have your $aAnswerList as key=>value, you can use $answer->setMultiOptions($aAnswerList) ;)